# tomcat Error 404 on doing run on server from eclipse to run springboot hibernate project

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, tomcat9

I am trying to create Spring Boot + Hibernate + REST project. When I try to do run on server for that project its giving me following tomcat response
[image]
When I checked on localhost:8080 its giving me error 404.
I am attaching my pom file and project structure as well.
Please let me know what to do in this case.
[image]
My tomcat version is 9.0
pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.akshay</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestHibernate</name>
    <description>Demo project to test hibernate and mysql</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 code means that path you tried to access (as you said 'localhost:8080' you tried to access path '/') is not defined inside the application. Your application is up and running and returns information that there is no mapping provided for this path. Try defining some Spring Controller on this path to do/return something.

Comment: I have added a controller class with @RequestMapping("/rest") this on class name and a method that returns a string has @GetMapping("/test") annotation to test.
I have tried this url
http://localhost:8080/TestHibernate/rest/test and the following one
http://localhost:8080/rest/test

Comment: In addition to `@RequestMapping` you need to add `@Controller` as well to tell spring to load this class as controller. And then this should be visible at `localhost:8080/rest/test`

Comment: I have already added @RestController annotation as i want to ping this from Postman

Comment: sure.
Just one more thing to mention.
When I run the bootstrap class, i can see the following url
http://localhost:8080/TestHibernate/WEB-INF/classes/com/akshay/TestHibernate/TestHibernateApplication.java

Comment: `
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class StudentController {

 @Autowired
 private StudentDAO studentDAO;

 @PostMapping("/saveStudent")
 public String save(@RequestBody Student student) {
  studentDAO.saveStudent(student);
  return "Saved Successfully";
 }
 
 @GetMapping("/test")
 public String test() {
  return "Success";
 }
}
`

Comment: I have added image for controller

Comment: Do you have something specified in `application.properties`? For example `server.servlet.context-path`? It may affect your path.

Comment: No.
#
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/hbstudent
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=root

#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000

#
# Hibernate properties
#
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.packagesToScan=com.akshay.entity
These are the contents of application.properties

Comment: I am not getting one more thing, how it is generating "http://localhost:8080/TestHibernate/WEB-INF/classes/com/akshay/TestHibernate/TestHibernateApplication.java" this url when I an doing run on server.
Ideally it should take http://localhost:8080/projectName when we execute.

Comment: I believe that this is more complicated than i thought but i think that this article will fix your problem. https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-example

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'll try by creating a new project using above link.